# jQuery window.send_to_editor function doesn't run

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a break point on my custom function. The breakpoint is paused in my console, so I believe it is being read, but my console.log('invoked') message and subsequent breakpoints are not triggered.

```
var capturePlaylistImage = function(ev) {
        console.log('called'); // This shows up in console
        var old_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;

        window.send_to_editor = function(html) { // breakpoint here
            console.log('invoked');
```

I get a thickbox for my send_to_editor call but when I insert the image into the post nothing happens - there's no thumbnail at my destination.

Why would my console.log('invoked') not be called?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console?  I notice you are missing the end parenthesis, which I assume was just not transferred, but it is difficult to see where the functions end without them.

Comment: No errors at all. There are closing brackets to these functions.